# tinymce - browse image button not visible on the Insert/Edit pop up

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

i am using the tinymce plugin for having formatted text in the textarea. I am also using the image Insert/Edit Images button(for inline images), but the browse file button does not seem to appear in the dialog boxes that opens after clicking it, so, i am not able to select a file now.

Below is the init of the plugin and some images of what i was hoping to see

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link code image | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            image_advtab: true,
            statusbar : false,
            menubar : false,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            force_br_newlines : true,
            convert_newlines_to_brs : true,
            forced_root_block : false,
            paste_text_linebreaktype : "br",
            width : 730,
            height : 300,
            templates: [
            {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
            {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
            ]
        });
```

[image: this is what i want ti to be like]
[image: this is what i have]

Comment: Have you filebrowser?

Comment: what is the filebrowser

Comment: About file browser [Doc1](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser) [Doc2](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:file_browser_callback)

Comment: You have a steady hand I see :)

Comment: okay, no i am not using any such thing yet, do i need to use it? a widow as i have pasted, already seems to appear, but no browse file button in it.

Comment: @Archer integration [elFinder](http://elfinder.org/) documentation https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-3.x

Comment: @Bora Thank you for the suggestion, i will implement it to see how it works. I have used the one specified in the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, after trying a few free file managers for tinymce, i came across [this](http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/) .

It is very easy to implement and the readme file give all the config necessary. This works perfectly good.

Comment: This is great! +1 from me.

Comment: it says you have to subscribe to https://creativesdk.adobe.com/ in http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/. Is that what you have done

Comment: Nope .. i have done no such thing. Probably things changed a bit since the post of this question.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score -2):

use the code snippet below to fix the problem

```
file_browser_callback: function (fieldName, url, type, win) {
    // your code         
},
```